# c# MongoDb filter on List<T>.Count

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Let the code speak for itself ;-)

```
public class SampleObject
{
    public List<string> SampleStrings {get;set;}
}
```

MongoDb related code:

```
// filter on SampleStrings.Count < 5
var filter = Builders<SampleObject>.Filter.Lt(so => so.SampleStrings.Count, 5)
```

**Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the serialization information for so=> so.SampleStrings.Count.**

Count() won't work either. Is there a MongoDb way?
Maybe one that perfectly integrates within the IFluent interface?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
var filter = Builders<SampleObject>.Filter.Not(
                      Builders<SampleObject>.Filter.Exists(so => so.SampleStrings[4]));
```

This will get translated into the following mongo db filter query:

```
"SampleStrings.4" : { "$exists" : false }
```

Saying that **the element at index 4 should not exists** is equivalent to say **the count of elements should be less than 5**.

Comment: You made me laugh. You are serious about this aren't you? :) MongoDb is such a creative tool to work with :)